# Why media files are storing in file system in Sitecore 10.3.I enabled Azure blob storage?

Tags: sitecore-client

I enabled blob storage using this article. What is the reason still files are stored on the file systems?

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/enable-the-azure-blob-storage-module-for-sitecore-blobs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, Sitecore should be storing your files in the database rather than on the file system.

If this is not the case, then its likely that some config changes have been made.

Please try logging in to the sitecore back end, then going to:

```
/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx
```

Please check to see if the setting `Media.UploadAsFiles` is `false` and `Media.DisableFileMedia` is `true`.

If this is not the case, then you should look in your config files and see where  this is set and try changing it to see if that works.

I believe with those settings switched over, the system will revert to storing as blobs. Then if you have enable the blob storage module correctly, it will push to storage instead of database.

More info here:
[How to store media files in file system](https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/08/07/how-to-store-media-files-in-file-system-instead-of-database/)